# Publishing Site creating a sub page

Tags: 2010, publishing-site, navigation

I have a publishing site. I have created a page in the site. Is it possible to createa  sub page from a page? I would like it to be added to the site navigation.

```
Main Site
    |_Page 1
    |_Page 2
        |_Page 2A
        |_Page 2B
        |_Page 2C
    |_Page 3
```

The only other way I could thinkg of doing it is:

```
Main Site
    |_Page 1
    |_Sub Site Page 2
        |_Page 2A
        |_Page 2B
        |_Page 2C
    |_Page 3
```

**Edit**

I don’t mind if in theory if Page 2A, 2B & 2C are stored at the same hierarchy as Page 2. In the navigation I want them to be a level down.

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to make pages from a subsite show in the navigation of the parent site?

Comment: Yes I will be. I think taht in the top site navigation you just need to tick sub site. Then I will get the sub site to inherit the parent site navigation.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You'd have to create new subwebs and on those create new pages to get this hierarchy.

Comment: If this is the case will need to think through how I was going to set things up. If no one else answers in the next day or so I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create any kind of structure in a XML file (irrespective of the page location) and consume it with XMLSiteMapProvider.
If you go for this solution, you have to maintain the xml manually yourself.